# Full calendar print angularjs

Tags: fullcalendar

full-calendar print preview is not having color in preview page.Its takes only black color.

I didn't get different colors in print preview using window.print()..Please answer..thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: Did you include fullcalendar.print.css in your page, or not?

Comment: yeah....i include that css..

Comment: Ok in that case you'll need to show us an example of your code and a screenshot of the problem. Are you sure it's not just that your printer is set to black and white mode?

Comment: $('#calendarwip').fullCalendar({                            
                            events: $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText),
                            eventRender: function (events, element) {                               
                                if (events.label == 'VaccInspDate') {                                  
                                                        
                                    element.css('color', 'Orange');                                    
                              }

Comment: Color is not displayed in print preview,,its my sample code

Comment: Its my print preview screen image..https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvpgH.png

Comment: please _edit the question_ with your code and screenshot URL, in the comments it's hard to read it.

Answer (score 0):

The fullCalendar print CSS says (among other things)

```
.fc-event{background:#fff!important;color:#000!important;pag‌​e-break-inside:avoid‌​}
```

So the `!important` will override anything in the main CSS and any styles you may have added yourself, and cause the events to have a very plain style, presumably so it will be ok on the majority of printers.

This is the default behaviour. If you want to change it, you can modify the print CSS file to your taste.